# Filtering array from object nested in array react

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object which objects have array, and my problem is to filter objects based on values from a nested array.

```
const skus = [{
        id: 1,
        features: ["Slim"],
        fields: [{
            label: "Material",
            value: "Material1"
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        features: ["Cotton"],
        fields: [{
            label: "Material",
            value: "Material2"
        }, ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        features: ["Slim"],
        fields: [{
            label: "Material",
            value: "Material3"
        }, ]
    }
];
```

output should be array based on features array, example:

```
const result = [{
    id: 2,
    features: ["Cotton"],
    fields: [{
            label: "Material",
            value: "Material2"
        },
        {
            label: "Type",
            value: "Type2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried to using filter method, but it only works on on objects, but not on arrays nested in objects

Comment: Exactly how do you go from the data given, `skus` to the desired result? Please clearly explain that and show your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
const filteredData = skus.filter((item) =>
     (item.fields.filter((field) => field.value === "Material2")).length !== 0
);
console.log(filteredData);
```

> I think this is what you meant...

Answer (score 0):

The Filter method allows you to delve deeper into an objects properties and perform comparisons.

```js
    const skus = [
                    { id: 1, features: ["Slim"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material1" },] },
                    { id: 2, features: ["Cotton"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material2" },] },
                    { id: 3, features: ["Slim"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material3" },] }
                ];
    
    let featureName = "Cotton"
    let results = skus.filter(s => s.features.includes(featureName))
    console.log(results);
```

I'm unsure where "{ label: "Type", value: "Type2" }" suddenly comes from in your results though?

Answer (score 0):

Well to understand  better you must understand that Array is also a special object only in javascript so you can perform filter on objects or the nested objects too.

```
skus.filter((item,keys)=>{
    return item['features'].includes("Cotton") // Pass the search term in includes
})
```

With this you can achieve your goal.
Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same output of the example you gave using :

```
skus.filter(sku => sku.features.includes("Cotton"));
```

I hope you can explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I write this code, and got same output,
I using id and value from index features

```js
const skus = [
    {
        id: 1,
        features: ['Slim'],
        fields: [
            {
                label: 'Material',
                value: 'Material1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        features: ['Cotton'],
        fields: [
            {
                label: 'Material',
                value: 'Material2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        features: ['Slim'],
        fields: [
            {
                label: 'Material',
                value: 'Material3'
            }
        ]
    }
]

const result = skus.filter(
    (item) => item.id === 2 && item.features[0] === 'Cotton'
)
console.log(result)
```